# SwiftUI return Bool from authorizationController async

Tags: firebase, swiftui, async-await, sign-in-with-apple

How could I return a Bool from this sign in with apple function that uses the authorizationController? I have been looking at withCheckedThrowingContinuation but with no luck. I have also seen some examples of using completion handlers but I would like to use async.

```
func signInWithApple(withState state: SignInState) async -> Bool {
    let request = signInWithAppleRequest(withState: state)
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}

func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    
    //...
        
        let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce)
        
        switch state {
        case .signIn:
            Task {
                authenticationState = .authenticating
                do {
                    let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
                    if result.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser == true {
                        self.isNewUser = true
                    }
                    return true
                } catch {
                    self.authenticationState = .unauthenticated
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return false
                }
            }
            
        case .reauth:
            Task {
                if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                    do {
                        try await user.reauthenticate(with: credential)
                        return true
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have all your types, so here is a simple example of a continuation which at least compiles.

The class must inherit from `NSObject` and adopt `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate`.

The continuation is set in the same scope where the request is executed.

The most important rule is: **The continuation must be resumed exactly once**

```
import AuthenticationServices

class Authorization: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    private var continuation : CheckedContinuation<ASAuthorization,Error>?
    
    func signInWithApple() async throws -> ASAuthorization {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
    
            self.continuation = continuation
            let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
            let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
            let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
            authorizationController.delegate = self
            authorizationController.performRequests()
        }
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        continuation?.resume(returning: authorization)
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }
}
```